# How to evaluate this notoriously hard exponential integral

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions

I am trying to evaluate the following integral
$$I = \int_{T}^{\infty} \exp\left[\beta t^{1-2H} - \gamma t^{2 - 2H} \right]t^{H-2} \log ^{\alpha}(t) \mbox{d}t$$
or alternatively if it is simpler in anyway
$$J = \int_{T}^{\infty} \exp\left[\beta t^{1-2H} - \gamma t^{2 - 2H} \right]t^{H-2} \left[(1-H) \log ^{\alpha}(t) - \alpha \log ^{\alpha - 1}(t)\right] \mbox{d}t$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are all non-zero constants and $H \in \left(0, 1\right)$

I have tried integrating by parts, differentiating under the integral sign (Feynman's technique), tried to substitute in $y = t^{2H}$ but have not had much luck.

Another thought i had was to try complete the square which gave an additional exp term.

Is there a way to compute this tricky integral.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

**edit**
Upon Substituting $\log (t) = y$, I get the following representation

$$\int_{e^T}^{\infty} y^{\alpha } \exp\left[\beta e^{(1-2 H) y}-\gamma  e^{(2-2 H) y}+(H-1) y\right] \mbox{d}y$$
not sure if it is much easier to work with.

**edit2**
How about an asymptotic form for the integral, will that be easier to derive ?

Comment: could you please redeem us from some of the notational clutter (= unnecessary many constants). thanks!

Comment: i only kept the constants so i could easily present the square completed integral. If you think the constants are too much nuisance, i'll  get rid of them but it will only reduce the integral by1 constant.

Comment: @tired I have removed the constants, I hope it helps

Comment: Where did this thing appear? @ComicBookGuy

Comment: It appears as part of much larger expressions bounding certain cumulative probability distribution function

Comment: I am now trying out the idea of substituting $\log (t) = y$.

Comment: What makes this "notoriously" hard? Is this integral know/used/referenced a lot?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could extend your offer, because I think to get through your question, but I need more time

Comment: @stocha, I'll be happy to extend the offer, but I am not sure how to do that. Do you know how i can ?

Comment: $I=\int y^{\alpha }\exp \left( \exp \left( y\right) \right) dy$

Comment: @ComicBookGuy, I just found a solution for the Integral $I=\int y^{\alpha }\exp \left( \exp \left( y\right) \right) dy$ in terms of a sum, which I think can be done, and can be generalized to your additional parameters. I cannot post the hole solution but I can show you the way to find it. I don't know, how to extend the offer, too.

Comment: @stocha, no worries, please feel free to share as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Ansatz}$ I was able to make some progress in calculating the antiderivative
$$I=\int \exp \left( -\beta \exp \left( t~\delta \right) \right) t^{\alpha }dt$$

where $\delta $ may set to 
$$\delta =1-2H\text{ or }\delta =2-2H$$
The integral may be expressed by the infinity sum

$$I\left( \alpha ,\beta ,\delta ,t\right) =\frac{1}{\delta ^{1+\alpha }}%
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\beta ^{k}\left( -1\right) ^{k-\alpha }}{%
k!k^{1+\alpha }}\Gamma \left( 1+\alpha ,-k~\delta ~t\right) +C$$
This can be simply proved by the differentiation. For some special values e.g. $\alpha=n>0$ explicit expressions can be obtained [stocha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596374/evaluating-int-t-infty-exp-left-beta-phi-t-rightt-frac32/2597472#2597472). A general expression is in work. For that an intensity study of similar methods, published in the standard publication of [MITTAG-LEFFLER FUNCTIONS] (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45870179_Mittag-Leffler_Functions_and_Their_Applications) has to be done.  Note that $k=0$ is a
problem, which has to be taken care of. 
In case of the integration limits $%
[0~~1]$ the sum can be split. If e.g. $\beta =\delta =1$

$$I\left( \alpha ,t\right) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left( -1\right)
^{k-\alpha }}{k!k^{1+\alpha }}\Gamma \left( 1+\alpha ,-k~t\right) $$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\exp \left( -\exp \left( t\right) \right) t^{\alpha }dt=\frac{1}{%
\alpha +1}+\left( I\left( 1\right) -I\left( 0\right) \right) $$

For other integration limits, one has to expand the integral e.g.

$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\int \exp \left( t~s-\exp \left( t\right) \right)
t^{\alpha }dt=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left(
-1\right) ^{1+k}}{k!\left( s-k\right) ^{1+\alpha }}\Gamma \left( 1+\alpha
,\left( s-k\right) ~t\right) $$

Note: This is the Laplacetransform of:

$$L\left[ \exp \left( -\beta \exp \left( t~\delta \right) \right) t^{\alpha }%
\right] $$

which may be calculated by the convolution theorem´[tattvamasi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374124/how-to-find-out-the-laplace-transform-of-the-product-of-two-functions).

$\textbf{Addendum}$ I finally managed to identify the infinity sum for $T=0$. In this case the solution may be expressed in terms of a $\lambda$-Generalized Hurwitz-Lerch- Zeta Function, which is defined e.g. in [Srivastava](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.428.9181&rep=rep1&type=pdf).