# Evaluating $\int_{T}^{\infty} \exp\left[\beta - \phi t \right]t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \log ^{\kappa}(t) \mbox{d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to evaluate the following integral 
\begin{eqnarray}
I(\phi, \beta, \kappa) = \int_{T}^{\infty} \exp\left[\beta - \phi t \right]t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \log ^{\kappa}(t) \mbox{d}t
\end{eqnarray}
where $\phi$ and $\beta$ are positive constants and $\kappa > -4$.

**Integration by parts for $I$**

Let $u = t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \log ^{\kappa}(t)$ and $\frac{dv}{dt} = \exp\left[\beta - \phi t \right]$  then using integration by parts formula I got
\begin{eqnarray}
- t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \log ^{\kappa}(t) \phi^{-1} \exp\left[\beta - \phi t \right] \mid_T^{\infty} + \phi^{-1} \int_{T}^{\infty} \exp\left[\beta - \phi t \right]\frac{(2 \kappa -3 \log (t)) \log ^{\kappa -1}(t)}{2 t^{5/2}} \mbox{d}t
\end{eqnarray}
I do n't think this new integral is simpler.

**Taylor Series expansion attempt for $I$**

Using Taylor Series expansion for the exponential term I get
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
&=& \int_{T}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left[\beta - \phi t \right]^n}{n!} t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \log ^{\kappa}(t) \mbox{d}t\\\nonumber
&=&   \int_{T}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{n!} {{n}\choose{k}} \beta^{n - k} (- \phi t)^k  t^{-\frac{3}{2}} \log^{\kappa}(t) \mbox{d}t\\
&=&   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}  \frac{1}{n!} {{n}\choose{k}}  \beta^{n - k} (- \phi)^k \int_{T}^{\infty} t^{-\frac{3}{2} + k} \log^{\kappa}(t) \mbox{d}t
\end{eqnarray}
For $k \neq 0$ the last integral does not converge, but i think my original integral should converge, even if conditionally.

Any suggestions how to evaluate this integral? 
Thank you

Comment: No I haven't I am not quite sure how to solve this problem with the laplace transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral $I\left( \phi ,\beta ,\kappa \right) $ can be evaluated for $\kappa =n\in N>0$:

$$I\left( \phi ,\beta ,n\right) =\exp \left( \beta \right) \int_{T}^{\infty
}\exp \left( -\phi \,t\right) t^{-\frac{3}{2}}\log \left( t\right) ^{n}dt$$

with the trick of [Jack D'Aurizio] ([Integrating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x (\log\tan x)^{2n+1}\;dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565726/integrating-int-0-frac-pi2-x-log-tan-x2n1-dx))

$$I\left( \phi ,\beta ,n\right) =\exp \left( \beta \right) \underset{\alpha
\rightarrow 0}{\lim }\frac{d^{n}}{d\alpha ^{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty }u^{\alpha -%
\frac{3}{2}}\exp \left( -\phi \,t\right) dt$$

Performing the integration:

$$I\left( \phi ,\beta ,n\right) =\exp \left( \beta \right) \sqrt{\phi }%
\underset{\alpha \rightarrow 0}{\lim }\frac{d^{2n+1}}{d\alpha ^{2n+1}}\phi
^{-\alpha }\Gamma \left( \alpha -\frac{1}{2},T~\phi \right)$$

the differentiation and take the limit as $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ leads to:

$$I\left( \phi ,\beta ,n\right) =\exp \left( \beta \right) \sqrt{\phi }%
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left( -1\right) ^{n-k}\left( \log [\phi ]\right)
^{n-k}\times $$
$$\times \Gamma \left( -\frac{1}{2},T~\phi \right) \left( \log [T~\phi
]\right) ^{k}+k!\sum_{m=1}^{k}\frac{\left( \log \left( T~\phi \right)
\right) ^{k-m}}{\left( k-m\right) !}G_{m+1,m+2}^{m+2,0}\left( T~\phi
\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
1,1,...,1 \\ 
0,0,...,0,-\frac{1}{2}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right)$$

where the general Leibniz rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and the [Wolfram Function side](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/20/02/01/) is used.

Comment: Thank you I will check the result and accept in the near future.

Comment: I evaluate your integral for $\kappa$ = n, because I have problems to find the Mellin-Transformation of M{exp(-exp(y)}, but anyway then lead to some kind of complex H-Fox-Function. If anyone have a hint to M{exp(-exp(y)}, we can go further.

Comment: I have a bounty open over a similar integral, it would be awesome if you can please take a look at that. In the bounty question. I am not surprised to hear that this showed up some connection to H  Fox function if you will like to share that calculation that will be educational for me and others as well, I think. Thank you once again

Comment: Thank you for your bounty, I have now an idea for the exact solution, I will try in the evening. Also I will consider the other question. Thanks

Comment: The idea does not work, the solution looked like a Mittag-Leffler-Function, so I'm left with $\kappa $ = $n$, I can take a look at your other integral, but I have no idea to solve this for any $\alpha$

Comment: That's all right thanks for trying, yeah it will be awesome if you can please take a look at the other problem I have open.

Comment: I looked at your nasty integral. My first idea was to solve it for T=0 and n>0 with the strategy [Sasha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334775/strategy-for-improper-integrals-related-to-the-beta-function-2/334936#334936) and the trick of the last integral. The derivatives of the H-Function are given in standard publication of Mathai: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266566090_The_H-function_Theory_and_Applications and then take the limit.